# How to find the least common multiple of a range of numbers?

Tags: javascript, function, math, recursion

Given an array of two numbers, let them define the start and end of a range of numbers.  For example, `[2,6]` means the range 2,3,4,5,6. I want to write javascript code to find the least common multiple for the range.  My code below works for small ranges only, not something like `[1,13]` (which is the range 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), which causes a stack overflow.  How can I efficiently find the least common multiple of a range?

```
function leastCommonMultiple(arr) {
    var minn, max;
    if ( arr[0] > arr[1] ) {
        minn = arr[1];
        max = arr[0];
    } else {
        minn = arr[0];
        max = arr[1];
    }
    function repeatRecurse(min, max, scm) {
        if ( scm % min === 0 && min < max ) {
            return repeatRecurse(min+1, max, scm);
        } else if ( scm % min !== 0 && min < max ) {
            return repeatRecurse(minn, max, scm+max);
        }
        return scm;
    } 
    return repeatRecurse(minn, max, max);
}
```

Comment: use `divide and conquer` algorithm approach instead of `recursion`

Comment: i still have no idea about divide and conquer algorithm that u mentioned...is is Euclidean algorithm??? i have no time for Euclidean but if all else fail, i do Euclidean....i really hope someone can use higher order function and memoize(var cache = {}) to solve this but i dont think it possible

Comment: @vinayakj - divide and conquer algorithms utilize recursion :)

Comment: I didnt mean algorithm and I also dont have any idea about Euclidean algorithm, I was just referring to algorithmic approach/problem solution approach

Comment: @rgbchris but in `divide and conquer` recursion doesnt have to happen with whole data, you do it on subsets so you wont have stack overflow

Comment: i think vinayakj mean tail optimization recursion???? the best example of divide and conquer is mergesort

Comment: yes...if min == max, the recursion loop would stop. i have to write repeatRecurse inside smallestCommons because that the best way to do it. Knowing tail optimization is something that would make my code handle maximum overstack error

Comment: Related (LCM of multiple numbers) and stunningly short: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722579/1066234

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think this gets the job done.

```
function leastCommonMultiple(min, max) {
    function range(min, max) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    function gcd(a, b) {
        return !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }

    function lcm(a, b) {
        return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);   
    }

    var multiple = min;
    range(min, max).forEach(function(n) {
        multiple = lcm(multiple, n);
    });

    return multiple;
}

leastCommonMultiple(1, 13); // => 360360
```

Comment: thanks rgbchris, i think ur code is Euclidean lol. either way, thank alot for the solution. it is CORRECT!

Comment: i cannot modify ur code to accept [1,13]...can u do it like that instead of (min,max)

Comment: if someone is wondering what is going on, good and simple explanation can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vWx5trbj6c, it explains relation between gcd and lcm, how to apply euclid`s algo and how it works.simple and easy to understand.

Comment: Msg from the future: can replace `var multiple = ... return multiple` with the oneliner `return range(min, max).reduce((a, b) => lcm(a, b), min)`

Answer (score 11):

As this question has recently been revived, here's what I think is a simpler take on the question, writing very simple helper functions to calculate the greatest common divisor of two integers (`gcd`), to calculate the least common multiple of two integers (`lcm`), to calculate the least common multiple of an array of integers (`lcmAll`), to generate the range of integers between two given integers (`rng`), and finally, in our main function, to calculate the least common multiple of the range of integers between two given integers (`lcmRng`):

```js
const gcd = (a, b) => b == 0 ? a : gcd (b, a % b)
const lcm = (a, b) =>  a / gcd (a, b) * b
const lcmAll = (ns) => ns .reduce (lcm, 1)
const rng = (lo, hi) => [...Array (hi - lo + 1)] .map ((_, i) => lo + i)

const lcmRng = (lo, hi) => lcmAll (rng (lo, hi))

console .log (lcmRng (1, 13))
```

All of these functions are simple.  Although the question was tagged *recursion*, only `gcd`is recursive. If this is an attempt to play with recursion, we could rewrite `lcmAll` in a recursive manner with something like this:

```
const lcmAll = (ns) => 
  ns.length == 0 
    ? 1 
    : lcm(ns[0], lcmAll(ns .slice (1)))
```

Although I'm a big fan of recursion, I see no other reason to choose the recursive version here over the `reduce` one.  In this case, `reduce` is cleaner.

And finally, if you really want the API originally requested where the range bounds are passed in an array, you could write one more wrapper:

```js
const leastCommonMultiple = ([lo, hi]) => lcmRng (lo, hi)

leastCommonMultiple ([1, 13]) //=> 360360
```

Comment: recursion is just so much fun. i like this `lcmAll = (x, ...more) => more.length ? lcm(x, lcmAll(...more)) : x`. maybe show `rng` with recursive implementation too?

Comment: That is nicer.  And of course `rng` is easy to do in a simple manner: `const rng = (lo, hi) => lo > hi ? [] : [lo, ...rng(lo + 1, hi)]`.

Answer (score 6):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max = Math.max(...arr);
  var min = Math.min(...arr);
  var candidate = max;

  var smallestCommon = function(low, high) {
    // inner function to use 'high' variable
    function scm(l, h) {
      if (h % l === 0) {
        return h;
      } else {
        return scm(l, h + high);
      }
    }
    return scm(low, high);
  };

  for (var i = min; i <= max; i += 1) {
    candidate = smallestCommon(i, candidate);
  }

  return candidate;
}

smallestCommons([5, 1]); // should return 60
smallestCommons([1, 13]); // should return 360360
smallestCommons([23, 18]); //should return 6056820
```

Answer (score 5):

LCM function for a range [a, b]

```js
// Euclid algorithm for Greates Common Divisor
function gcd(a, b)
{ 
 return !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
} 

// Least Common Multiple function
function lcm(a, b) 
{
 return a * (b / gcd(a,b));
}

// LCM of all numbers in the range of arr=[a, b] 
function range_lcm(arr)
{
 // Swap [big, small] to [small, big]
 if(arr[0] > arr[1]) (arr = [arr[1], arr[0]]);

 for(x = result = arr[0]; x <= arr[1]; x++) {
  result = lcm(x, result);
 }
 
 return result; 
}

alert(range_lcm([8, 5])); // Returns 840
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the other answers to be somewhat confusing while I was figuring out the best way to do this with just two numbers, so I looked found the most optimal solution on Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Calculation

The most efficient way to find the least common multiple of two numbers is `(a * b) / greatestCommonDivisor(a, b);`

To do this we need to calculate the greatest common denominator. The most efficient way to do that is using Euclid's algorithm.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclid's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclid%27s_algorithm)

Here is the complete solution for two numbers in case anyone else lands on this question but only needs to calculate for two numbers:

```
const leastCommonMultiple = (a, b) => (a * b) / greatestCommonDivisor(a, b);

const greatestCommonDivisor = (a, b) => {
  const remainder = a % b;
  if (remainder === 0) return b;
  return greatestCommonDivisor(b, remainder);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Mine is not as fancy as the other answers but I think it is easy to read.

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
 //order our array so we know which number is smallest and which is largest
 var sortedArr = arr.sort(sortNumber),
 //the smallest common multiple that leaves no remainder when divided by all the numbers in the rang
 smallestCommon = 0,
 //smallest multiple will always be the largest number * 1;
 multiple = sortedArr[1];

 while(smallestCommon === 0) {
  //check all numbers in our range
  for(var i = sortedArr[0]; i <= sortedArr[1]; i++ ){
   if(multiple % i !== 0 ){
    //if we find even one value between our set that is not perfectly divisible, we can skip to the next multiple
    break;
   }

   //if we make it all the way to the last value (sortedArr[1]) then we know that this multiple was perfectly divisible into all values in the range
   if(i == sortedArr[1]){
    smallestCommon = multiple;
   }

  }

  //move to the next multiple, we can just add the highest number.
  multiple += sortedArr[1];
 }

 console.log(smallestCommon);
 return smallestCommon;
}

function sortNumber(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}


smallestCommons([1, 5]); // should return 60.
smallestCommons([5, 1]); // should return 60.
smallestCommons([1, 13]); // should return 360360.
smallestCommons([23, 18]); // should return 6056820.
```

Edit: Turned answer into snippet.

Comment: Liked this one, but the .sort() in the beginning would sort them alphabetically: [5,10] would be sorted to [10,5]. A minor glitch but worth fixing.

Comment: Good catch @isacvale ! I have updated the sort with a custom function to sort numerically instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-recursive version of your original approach.

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // Sort the array
  arr = arr.sort(function (a, b) {return a - b}); // numeric comparison;
  var min = arr[0];
  var max = arr[1];

  var numbers = [];
  var count = 0;

  //Here push the range of values into an array
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  //Here freeze a multiple candidate starting from the biggest array value - call it j
  for (var j = max; j <= 1000000; j+=max) {

    //I increase the denominator from min to max
    for (var k = arr[0]; k <= arr[1]; k++) {

      if (j % k === 0) { // every time the modulus is 0 increase a counting 
        count++; // variable
      }
    }

    //If the counting variable equals the lenght of the range, this candidate is the least common value
    if (count === numbers.length) { 
      return j; 
    }
    else{
      count = 0; // set count to 0 in order to test another candidate
    }
  }
}

alert(smallestCommons([1, 5]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I came across this page and wanted to share my solution :)

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]),
      min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]),
      i = 1;
  while (true) {
    var count = 0;
    for (j = min; j < max; j++) {
      if (max * i % j !== 0) {
        break;
      }
      count++;
    }
    if (count === (max - min)) {
      alert(max * i);
      return max * i;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
smallestCommons([23, 18]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
    arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    let range = []
    for (let i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
        range.push(i)
    }

    for(let i = arr[1]; ; i++){
        if(range.every((num => i % num == 0))){
            return i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
 function leastCommonMultiple(arr) {
    /*
      function range(min, max) {
        var arr = [];
       for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
      }
       return arr;
    }
    */
    var min, range;
     range = arr;
    if(arr[0] > arr[1]){
       min = arr[1];
    }
    else{
       min = arr[0]
    }

    function gcd(a, b) {
        return !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
    }

    function lcm(a, b) {
        return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);   
    }

   var multiple = min;
    range.forEach(function(n) {
       multiple = lcm(multiple, n);
    });

   return multiple;
}
```

console.log( leastCommonMultiple([1, 13]) )

Comment: hang on, i see my mistake

Comment: i cannot even undderstand that Eucliden gcd algorithm

Comment: Did you copy the answer you accepted just to change the function's signature from two integers to an array of two integers?

Comment: yes. i change 2 integers to determine min max from the array input

Answer (score 0):

Well played on the solution. I think I got one that might be abit shorter just for future reference but ill definatly look into yours

```
function LCM(arrayRange) {
    var newArr = [];

    for (var j = arrayRange[0]; j <= arrayRange[1]; j++){
        newArr.push(j);
    }

    var a = Math.abs(newArr[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        var b = Math.abs(newArr[i]),
            c = a;

        while (a && b) {
            a > b ? a %= b : b %= a;
        }
        a = Math.abs(c * newArr[i] / (a + b))
    }
   return console.log(a);
}

LCM([1,5]);
```

Comment: you should add : `if (arrayRange[0] > arrayRange[1]) arrayRange.reverse() ;` at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

You may have originally had a stack overflow because of a typo: you switched between `min` and `minn` in the middle of `repeatRecurse` (you would have caught that if `repeatRecurse` hadn’t been defined in the outer function).  With that fixed, `repeatRecurse(1,13,13)` returns 156.

The obvious answer to avoiding a stack overflow is to turn a recursive function into a non-recursive function.  You can accomplish that by doing:

```
function repeatRecurse(min, max, scm) {
    while ( min < max ) {
        while ( scm % min !== 0 ) {
            scm += max;
        }
        min++;
    }
}
```

But perhaps you can see the mistake at this point: you’re not ensuring that `scm` is still divisible by the elements that came before `min`.  For example, `repeatRecurse(3,5,5)=repeatRecurse(4,5,15)=20`.  Instead of adding `max`, you want to replace `scm` with its least common multiple with `min`.  You can use rgbchris’s gcd (for integers, `!b` is the same thing as `b===0`).  If you want to keep the tail optimization (although I don’t think any javascript engine has tail optimization), you’d end up with:

```
function repeatRecurse(min, max, scm) {
    if ( min < max ) {
        return repeatRecurse(min+1, max, lcm(scm,min));
    }
    return scm;
}
```

Or without the recursion:

```
function repeatRecurse(min,max,scm) {
    while ( min < max ) {
        scm = lcm(scm,min);
        min++;
    }
    return scm;
}
```

This is essentially equivalent to rgbchris’s solution. A more elegant method may be divide and conquer:

```
function repeatRecurse(min,max) {
    if ( min === max ) {
        return min;
    }
    var middle = Math.floor((min+max)/2);
    return lcm(repeatRecurse(min,middle),repeatRecurse(middle+1,max));
}
```

I would recommend moving away from the original argument being an array of two numbers.  For one thing, it ends up causing you to talk about two different arrays: `[min,max]` and the range array.  For another thing, it would be very easy to pass a longer array and never realize you’ve done something wrong.  It’s also requiring several lines of code to determine the min and max, when those should have been determined by the caller.

Finally, if you’ll be working with truly large numbers, it may be better to find the least common multiple using the prime factorization of the numbers.

Comment: Hi Teepee, first thanks for trying so hard. but my code in the original post with 'minn' is not a mistake. Withouth 'minn', the answer is wrong. Yes, it wrong without 'minn'. Second function repeatRecurse(min, max, scm) {
        while ( min < max ) {
            while ( scm % min !== 0 ) {
                scm += max;
           }
           min++;
         }
   } doesnt work. I will try to modify it to work hopefully. I havent try ur other two snippets of codes. yet. so busy my friend. very busy, going headache here lol. peace

Comment: also for javascript tail optimization recursion, i dont know the whole detail or mechanism of how it work yet because I didnt read/study that part in Allonge Javascript. I will in the future soon. so much to learn

Comment: @johnnyjoe Oh.  In that case, my edit broke your original code, which I shouldn't have done (sorry about that).  My guess then as to why you had a stack overflow is that you only increment by `max` each time.  Which means that your stack depth is `finalAnswer/max`.  For `[1,13]`, this is `360,360/13=27720` levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
function range(min, max) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

function gcd (x, y) {
  return (x % y === 0) ? y : gcd(y, x%y);
}

function lcm (x, y) {
  return (x * y) / gcd(x, y); 
}

function lcmForArr (min, max) {
  var arr = range(min, max);
  return arr.reduce(function(x, y) {
    return lcm(x, y); 
  });
}

range(10, 15); // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
gcd(10, 15); // 5
lcm(10, 15); // 30
lcmForArr(10, 15); //60060
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```js
// Euclid Algorithm for the Greatest Common Denominator
function gcd(a, b) {
    return !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
  }
  // Euclid Algorithm for the Least Common Multiple

function lcm(a, b) {
    return a * (b / gcd(a, b));
  }
  // LCM of all numbers in the range of arr = [a, b];

function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var i, result;
  // large to small - small to large
  if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
    arr.reverse();
  } // only happens once. Means that the order of the arr reversed.
  for (i = result = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) { // all numbers up to arr[1] are arr[0].
    result = lcm(i, result); // lcm() makes arr int an integer because of the arithmetic operator.
  }
  return result;
}
smallestCommons([5, 1]); // returns 60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function lcm(arr) {
  var max = Math.max(arr[0],arr[1]),
      min = Math.min(arr[0],arr[1]),
      lcm = max;
  var calcLcm = function(a,b){
    var mult=1;
    for(var j=1; j<=a; j++){
      mult=b*j;
      if(mult%a === 0){
        return mult;
      }
    }
  };
  for(var i=max-1;i>=min;i--){
    lcm=calcLcm(i,lcm);
  }
  return lcm;
}
lcm([1,13]); //should return 360360.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*Function to calculate sequential numbers 
in the range between the arg values, both inclusive.*/
    function smallestCommons(arg1, arg2) {
     
       if(arg1>arg2) { // Swap arg1 and arg2 if arg1 is greater than arg2
          var temp = arg1;
          arg1 = arg2;
          arg2 =temp;
        }
      
      /*
      Helper function to calculate greatest common divisor (gcd)
      implementing Euclidean algorithm */
      function gcd(a, b) {
       return b===0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b); 
       }
      
      /*
      Helper function to calculate lowest common multiple (lcm) 
of any two numbers using gcd function above */
       function lcm(a,b){
          return (a*b)/gcd(a,b);
         }
      
      var total = arg1; // copy min value
      for(var i=arg1;i<arg2;i++){
          total = lcm(total,i+1);
         }
      //return that total
      return total;
    }
    /*Yes, there are many solutions that can get the job done.
    Check this out, same approach but different view point.
    */
    console.log(smallestCommons(13,1)); //360360
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I hope you will find it easy to follow:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
  var max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

  var smallestCommon = min * max;

  var doneCalc = 0;

  while (doneCalc === 0) {
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      if (smallestCommon % i !== 0) {
        smallestCommon += max;
        doneCalc = 0;
        break;
      }
      else {
        doneCalc = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return smallestCommon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another nonrecursive for-loop solution

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var biggestNum = arr[0];
  var smallestNum = arr[1];
  var thirdNum;
  //make sure biggestNum is always the largest
  if (biggestNum < smallestNum) {
    thirdNum = biggestNum;
    biggestNum = smallestNum;
    smallestNum = thirdNum;
  }
  var arrNum = [];
  var count = 0;
  var y = biggestNum;

  // making array with all the numbers fom smallest to biggest
  for (var i = smallestNum; i <= biggestNum; i += 1) {
    arrNum.push(i);
  }

  for (var z = 0; z <= arrNum.length; z += 1) {
    //noprotect
    for (y; y < 10000000; y += 1) {
      if (y % arrNum[z] === 0) {
        count += 1;
        break;
      }
      else if (count === arrNum.length) {
        console.log(y);
        return y;
      }
      else {
        count = 0;
        z = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
smallestCommons([23, 18]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var sortedArr = arr.sort(); // sort array first
  var tempArr = []; // create an empty array to store the array range
  var a = sortedArr[0];
  var b = sortedArr[1];
  for(var i = a; i <= b; i++){
    tempArr.push(i);
  }
  // find the lcm of 2 nums using the Euclid's algorithm
  function gcd(a, b){
    while (b){
      var temp = b;
      b = a % b;
      a = temp;
    }
    return a;
  }

  function lcm(a, b){
    return Math.abs((a * b) / gcd(a, b));
  }
  var lcmRange = tempArr.reduce(lcm);


  return lcmRange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
    let smallest, biggest, min;
    arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        biggest = Math.max(a, b);
    });
    const max = biggest;
    arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        smallest = Math.min(a, b);
        min = smallest;
    });
    check: while (true) {
        biggest += max;
        for (min = smallest; min < max; min++) {
            if (biggest % min != 0) {
                continue check;
            }
            if (min == (max - 1) && biggest % min == 0) {
                console.warn('found one');
                return biggest;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function smallestCommons(arr) {
      let min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
      let max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);
      let scm = max;

      //calc lcm of two numbers:a,b;
      const calcLcm = function(a, b) {
        let minValue = Math.min(a, b);
        let maxValue = Math.max(a, b);
        let lcm = maxValue;
        while (lcm % minValue !== 0) {
          lcm += maxValue;
        }
        return lcm;
      }

      //calc scm in range of arr;
      for (let i = max; i >= min; i--) {
        scm = calcLcm(scm, i);
      }
      console.log(scm);
      return scm;
    }

    smallestCommons([1, 13]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another very simple way and have low complexity.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  let smallestNum = arr[0] < arr[1] ? arr[0] : arr[1];
  let greatestNum = arr[0] > arr[1] ? arr[0] : arr[1];
  let initalsArr = [];
  for(let i = smallestNum; i <= greatestNum; i++){
    initalsArr.push(i);
  }
  let notFoundFlag = true;
  let gNMltpl = 0;
  let filteredArrLen; 
  while(notFoundFlag){
    gNMltpl += greatestNum;
    filteredArrLen = initalsArr.filter((num)=>{
      return (gNMltpl / num) === Math.floor((gNMltpl / num)) 
    }).length;
    if(initalsArr.length == filteredArrLen){
      notFoundFlag = false;
    }
  }
  return gNMltpl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using es6 feature is

Lcm of given numbers

```
  const gcd = (a, b) => (!b ? a : gcd(b, a % b));

  const lcm = (a, b) => a * (b / gcd(a, b));

  const getLcm = (arr) => {

    const numbers = arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));

    let result = parseInt(numbers[0]);

    for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      result = lcm(parseInt(result), parseInt(numbers[i + 1]));
    }

    return result;
  };
```

Hcf of given numbers

```
  const getHcf = (arr) => {

    const numbers = arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));

    let result = parseInt(numbers[0]);

    for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      result = gcd(parseInt(numbers[i]), parseInt(result));
    }

    return result;
  };
```

Call like this

```
  console.log(getLcm([20, 15, 10, 40])). Answer 120

  console.log(getHcf([2, 4, 6, 8, 16])). Answer 2
```

Comment: Did you test this code before you published it?  Either your boundaries or your index is incorrect in the loop for `getLcm`.  The cleanest fix is to replace `[i + 1]` with `[i]`.  But really, I think it's a lot simpler to actually use a `reduce`: `const getLcm = (arr) => arr .reduce(lcm, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I also found myself working on this challenge on my [freeCodeCamp JavaScript Certification](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple). This is what I have been able to come up with:

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {

    let newArr = [];
  
    // create a new array from arr [min, min + 1,......., max - 1, max]
    for (let i = Math.min(...arr); i <= Math.max(...arr); i++){
      newArr.push(i);
    }
  
    // let the max of newArr be the smallestCommonMultiple initially
    let largest = Math.max(...newArr);
    let smallestCommonMultiple = largest;
    
    // If the supposedly smallestCommonMultiple fail on any of elements in 
    //newArr add the max element until we find the smallestCommonMultiple. 
    while (newArr.some(element => smallestCommonMultiple % element !== 0)){
      smallestCommonMultiple += largest; 
    }
  
    return smallestCommonMultiple; 
 }
 
 console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18]));
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it will work.

```
 var a = [2, 6];
    
    function getTotalX(a) {
      var num = 1e15;
      var i; 
      var arr = [];
      for (i = 1; i <=num ; i++){
        arr.push(i);
      }
     
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        var filterArr = arr.filter((val, ind, arr) => (val % a[i] === 0));
      }
      
     console.log(filterArr[0]); // will return 6
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a similar function in typescript that does the same task but only without recursion...

```
function findLowestCommonMultipleBetween(start: number, end: number): number {
  let numbers: number[] = [];

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }

  for (let i = 1; true; i++) {
    let divisor = end * i;

    if (numbers.every((number) => divisor % number == 0)) {
      return divisor;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do note the performance issue with this.  If I run `findLowestCommonMultipleBetween(1, 25)`, it takes 30 seconds on my mid-range laptop, compared to sub-1ms runs for the accepted answer (or for my answer, and probably for all the mathematical ones.)  Math can come in handy!  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Your code is admirably faster. Though, I was mostly focusing on refactoring mine :)

Comment: Sure, and I rarely ever focus on performance.  But sometimes you do need to think about it.  Sometimes it's just a matter of realizing that a naive approach is *too* naive for the problem.  I think this is one of those problems as least-common-multiples can grow really quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
    let min = Math.min(...arr);
    let max = Math.max(...arr);
    let rangArr = [];
    for(let i = min; i <= max; i++) rangArr.push(i);
    let smallestCommon = max;
    while(!rangArr.every(e => smallestCommon % e === 0)){
        smallestCommon += max;
    }
    return smallestCommon;
}


console.log(smallestCommons([1, 13]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // Kind of a brute force method, It's not fancy but it's very simple and easy to read :P

  // make an array with all the numbers in the range.
  let numbersArr = [];
  for (let i = Math.min(...arr); i <= Math.max(...arr); i++) {
    numbersArr.push(i);
  }

  // keep multiplying the biggest number until it's divisible by all the numbers in the numbersArr array.
  let scm = Math.max(...arr);
  while (true) {
    if (numbersArr.every(num => scm % num === 0)) {
      return scm;
    } else {
      scm += Math.max(...arr);
    }
  }
}

smallestCommons([2, 10]); // returns 2520.
smallestCommons([1, 13]); // returns 360360.
smallestCommons([23, 18]); // returns 6056820.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function leastCommonMultiple(arr) {
  // Setup
  const [min, max] = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  // Largest possible value for LCM
  let upperBound = 1;
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    upperBound *= i;
  }
  // Test all multiples of 'max'
  for (let multiple = max; multiple <= upperBound; multiple += max) {
    // Check if every value in range divides 'multiple'
    let divisorCount = 0;
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      // Count divisors
      if (multiple % i === 0) {
        divisorCount += 1;
      }
    }
    if (divisorCount === max - min + 1) {
      return multiple;
    }
  }
}

//for a test
leastCommonMultiple([1, 5]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function findSmallestCommonMultipleOfRangeOfNumbers(arr) {
let sortedArr = arr.concat([]).sort((a,b)=> a-b)
let min = sortedArr[0]
let max = sortedArr[1]
function range(min, max) {
const myRangeArr = [];
for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
myRangeArr.push(i);
}
return myRangeArr;
}

function gcd(a, b) {
return !b ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

function lcm(a, b) {
return (a * b) / gcd(a, b); 
}

let smallestCommonMultiple = min;
range(min, max).forEach(function(n) {
smallestCommonMultiple = lcm(smallestCommonMultiple, n);
});

return smallestCommonMultiple;
}

console.log(findSmallestCommonMultipleOfRangeOfNumbers([23,18]));
```