# Least Common Multiple of an array values using Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor, lcm

I want to calculate the least common multiple of an array of values, using Euclideans algorithm

I am using this pseudocode implementation: found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

```
function gcd(a, b)
    while b ≠ 0
       t := b; 
       b := a mod b; 
       a := t; 
    return a;
```

My javascript implementation is such

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {

  var gcm = arr.reduce(function(a,b){

    let minNum = Math.min(a,b);
    let maxNum = Math.max(a,b);
    var placeHolder = 0;

    while(minNum!==0){
        placeHolder = maxNum;
        maxNum = minNum;
        minNum = placeHolder%minNum;
    } 

    return (a*b)/(minNum);
  },1);

  return gcm;
}


smallestCommons([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

I get error, on my whileloop

> Infinite loop

**EDIT** Some corrections were made, at the end of gcm function, I used 0 as the initial start value, it should be 1, since you can't have a gcm from 0.

**EDIT2** The expected output should be 60, since thats the least common multiple of 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### With ES6

```
const gcd = (a, b) => a ? gcd(b % a, a) : b;

const lcm = (a, b) => a * b / gcd(a, b);
```

Then use reduce on given array of integers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(lcm); // Returns 60
```

---

#### With ES5

```
var gcd = function (a, b) {
    return a ? gcd(b % a, a) : b;
}

var lcm = function (a, b) {
    return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}
```

Then use reduce on given array of integers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(lcm); // Returns 60
```

Comment: Beautiful because stunningly short and to the point. Best answer IMO.

Comment: I really like how concise the ES6 version is! Great work, Елин Й.!

Comment: Superb clean solution, I'm very impressed :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you intentionally tangle all variables and operator sequence? ;-)

```
  while(minNum!==0){
        placeHolder = minNum;
        minNum = maxNum % minNum;
        maxNum = placeHolder;
    } 

    //here maxNum = GCD(a,b)

    return (a*b) / (maxNum);  //LCM
```

Comment: probably since I wrote the formula after watching a video, then looked at wiki ;s