# Least Common Multiple - for loop breaks down - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, lcm

I'm taking a course on FreeCodeCamp.org and the assignment is to find "Smallest Common Multiple". So I came up with a solution I think works and I does up to a certain point. Then the code just seems like it's breaking down. Here is my code:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr = arr.sort((a,b) => {return a - b;});
  console.log(arr);
  var truesec = false;
  for(var a = arr[1]; truesec != true; a++){

    for(var e = 1; e <= arr[1]; e++){
      //console.log(a % e + " " + e);
      if(a % e != 0){
        truesec = false;
        break;
      }else{
        truesec = true;
      }
    }
    //console.log(truesec + " " + a);
    if(truesec == true){
      return a;
    }
  }

  return a;
}


console.log(smallestCommons([23,18]));
```

This should return `6056820` according to their checklist but every time I check I get a different result I've gotten both `114461` & `122841` from the same code. Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with this?

Here is the assignment if it helps:
[Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Smallest Common Multiple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWZlQ.png)

Comment: Seem like is is not breaking but taking a lot of time... I believe you should re-think your algorithm - this is VERY heavy brute force...

Comment: I would suggest to calculate the gcd (greatest common devider) of a and b (gcd(a,b)). For this you just should check out an implementation of the Euclidean algorithm (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) Once you can get the lcm ( least/smallest common multiplier) by following division lcm(a,b) = a*b / gcd(a,b)

Comment: `arr = arr.sort` is unnecessar re-assignment since `sort` changes `arr` already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a different approach to this problem:

1. create function to get all prime factors
2. create array of prime factor of all number between `a[0]` and `a[1]`
3. reduce the array as the biggest power for each prime factor.
4. multiple all the prime factor left in the array

Your approach will take `O(k*a[1])` when `k` is the answer - and `k` can be very high... This approach will take `O((a[1])^2)`

Consider the following code:

```
function smallestCommons2(arr) {
    arr.sort((a,b) => {return a - b;});
    let factors = [];
    for(let i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++)
        factors.push(findPrimeFactors(i));

    let reduced = reduceFactors(factors);
    let ans = 1;
    for (let i in reduced)
        ans *= Math.pow(i, reduced[i]);
    return ans;
}

function reduceFactors(factorsArr) {
    let factorObject = {};
    for (let i in factorsArr) {
        for(let key in factorsArr[i]) {
            if (!(key in factorObject) || factorObject[key] < factorsArr[i][key])
                factorObject[key] = factorsArr[i][key];
        }
    }
    return factorObject;
}

function findPrimeFactors (num) {
    var primeFactors = [];
    while (num % 2 === 0) {
        primeFactors.push(2);
        num = num / 2;
    }

    var sqrtNum = Math.sqrt(num);
    for (var i = 3; i <= sqrtNum; i++) {
        while (num % i === 0) {
            primeFactors.push(i);
            num = num / i;
        }
    }
    if (num > 2)
        primeFactors.push(num);

    let factorObject = {};

    for (let item of primeFactors) {
        if (item in factorObject)
            factorObject[item] += 1;
        else factorObject[item] = 1;
    }
    return factorObject;
}


console.log(smallestCommons2([23,18]));
```

This code will output `6056820` in sec

**Edited** - found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302607/6487675) that do the same thing in a better way

Comment: This surely works but it's a bit more advanced then what I can understand yet. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

What your algorithm trying to do is find the common multiple **between 1 and the greater number in the array**, which might take a very long time. However, the question from the FreeCodeCamp asks you to find the common multiple **between the two numbers in the array**, so the result calculated from your algorithm does not match the tests.

To make your solution works, you can change

from `for (var e = 1; e <= arr[1]; e++)`

to `for (var e = arr[0]; e <= arr[1]; e++)`

in order to loop between two numbers in the array.